# Writing ITK (insight Toolkit) results to local buffer

Tags: c++, itk

#### After applying an ITK filter pipeline, how do I write back the result to a buffer to be used (outside ITK)?

The [*Insight Software Guide*](http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf) has an example *Book 1: Chapter 4.1.7: "Importing Image Data from a Buffer"*, and the same example is also found in the [WikiExamples](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ImportImageFilter).

It shows how one can wrap a ITK pointer around a C++ array to use it further by using the `ImportImageFilter` object.
However, this example then uses a `Writer` object to write the filtered result to a file.

How do I write the filtered result into another C++ array instead? Or how do I overwrite the array I've used as input?

In essence, I've an application which contains an image in a buffer (`localBuffer`) which I can wrap following the example code:

```
 [...]
 const bool filterOwnsBuffer= false;    
 importFilter->SetImportPointer( localBuffer, size[0]*size[1], filterOwnsBuffer );
```

I can then use it it in any itk pipeline and 'update' it at a certain stage:

```
[...]
FilterType::Pointer filter = FilterType::New();
filter->SetInput( importFilter->GetOutput() );
filter->Update();
```

How do I now ensure that `localbuffer` has the filtered values? Or, alternatively, how do I set a different `resultbuffer` to the output values? Do I have to use the image iterator and 'loop' over my buffer manually? Or can I use the `filter->GetOutput()` more directly?

A little code example or a link to an according example would be very much appreciated.
(Simply the  *"Exporting Image Data to a Buffer"* equivalent to the given import example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageType::Pointer output = filter->GetOutput();
ImageType::PixelContainer * outputContainer = output->GetPixelContainer();
ImageType::PixelContainer::Element * resultBuffer = outputContainer->GetBufferPointer();
```

See the [Image](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1Image.html) documentation and [ImportImageContainer](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImportImageContainer.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. I assume Provided that I have a pointer to my resultBuffer already (from my application), can I use outputContainer->GetBufferPointer() do directly assign? (Matching type and writing order assumed of course.) [ I'll read up on the documentation, though. ]

Comment: As I've understood it, *resultBuffer is now a pointer the results, but the buffer is still a different memory location than I might have had prepared beforehand. Provided that I have an allocated results-memory (from my application) already, how do I tell itk to use this memory as a buffer? (Of course memory size needs to be correct.) i.e. I have a (float *) dst  Destination-pointer to a continuous memory of appropriate size.

Comment: If the filter you are using is an InPlaceImageFilter, http://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1InPlaceImageFilter.html, it is possible to re-use the input memory.  Otherwise, it might be possible to use the SetOutput method.  A call to UpdateOutputInformation() on the filter will case the output information on the image to be populated with the correct parameters.

Comment: I think it should be edited to "ImageType::PixelContainer * outputContainer = output->GetPixelContainer();"

Comment: I have the same question, can the container reuse the allocated buffer? If wanna use a allocated image as the result image, `im=filter->GetOutput()`, will ITK reuse the im than create a temp image, copy to im and destory the temp image?

Comment: @7oud it sounds like you want the itk::ImportImageFilter: https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImportImageFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the remedy for me:

```
memcpy( buffer, filter->GetOutput()->GetBufferPointer(),
         size[0]*size[1]*sizeof(InputPixelType));
```

This works because by the time the filter is destroyed the buffer was already parsed to "buffer", which is the pointer to your data.